# When I click 'View Code' excel stops respoding

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I use excel 2016. When I open a new workbook, I right click on 'sheet1' and select 'view code'. When I complete this action excel stops responding. This also occurs when I click the 'visual basic' button on the developer ribbon. I have researched this problem and the only answers I could find references excel that stops responding after VBA script was executed. In this case; no script is being executed, it is only in an attempt to open VBA, which in turn, causes excel to stop responding. I have also checked the auto recover directory and there seem to be no anomalies there either.

Comment: is there a personal workbook in excel ? is it on your personal machine or a locally used machine?

Comment: also provide some sort of screenshot

Comment: There are no messages, following the actions described above excel stops responding and no further action can be completed except for to close down the program. Yes there is a personal workbook in the auto-recover directory

Comment: try remove the personal workbook.xlsb

Comment: What about my existing code? if I do this then all the existing code will be lost.

Comment: I've had this problem before! 1. Close Excel. 2. Rename the `Personal.xlsb` file as 'Ex Personal.xlsb` ..or anyhting else to stop excel loading it automatically. 3. Double click this renamed file. Excel will ask you if you want to repair it. Answer "Yes". Save from the VBA screen but when asked to "Overwrite" click "NO" and rename as "PERSONAL.XLSB"

Comment: if its a blank workbook ,why would there be any code in it?

Comment: @mo.h he never said the personal workbook is blank

Comment: @VictorMoraes he said when he opens a "new workbook"

Comment: @mo.h new workbook means a new file, but PERSONAL.XLSB is a separated workbook, separated from the user workbook. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566)

Comment: @VictorMoraes  if you have a personal workbook it doesn't make a difference. Every time you open excel it will be there because it's built into excel, not an individual file.

Comment: @mo.h You told OP to remove the personal workbook.xlsb (`Personal.xlsb`) and OP said there is code in it, which then you asked "if it is a blank workbook, why would there be any code in it?" See the confusion?

Comment: @MiguelH thank you, but this did not work; I renamed the file as per your instruction and when I double-click the renamed file, excel opens it's shell without asking for a repair. When I open a new workbook and click on 'view code' the result is still the same.

Comment: @VictorMoraes exactly. If he opens a new excel workbook, how can there be any code other than taht which is contained in personal?

Comment: @mo.h didn't you told him to remove the Personal.xlsb, where all of his code is stored, therefore removing all of his code? Anyways, this discussion is already off topic and not helping OP

Comment: Gentleman, I click on 'view code' on a sheet when a new workbook or any workbook is open to open VBA (Just my preference). When the excel shell is blank you can open VBA without having any workbook open, by pressing ALT+F11 or by clicking the 'Visual Basic' button on the dev ribbon. A new workbook really has nothing to do with it, so my apologies for any confusion caused. When I delete the personal workbook from XLSTART dir then the problem is resolved but I cannot access any of the code that I regularly use contained in my original Personal.xlsb file.

Comment: So can you export the various Modules,Forms etc in your Personal.xls view in the VBA code view? If you can then export each Form, Module, Class to file. Then start deleting Modules/Forms/Classes starting from your most recent addition. Close / reopen Excel after each deletion to see if there is a chunk of existing code which might be causing your problem!,